# Plotting Euro Symbol € in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, euro

Euro Symbol `€` is shown as `...` at PDF output

```
ggplot() + theme_bw() + geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(formatter = "euro")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ISOLatin9.enc` encoding when starting PDF graphics

```
pdf(encoding = "ISOLatin9.enc")
```

At http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/text.html is said that euro symbol can selecting ISO-8895-15 (Latin-9) which has the Euro as character

Answer (score 2):

Here are 3 methods to format numbers in "EU" format:

```
 # 1. Method 1
 library(scales)
 euro <- dollar_format(prefix = "\u20ac", big.mark = ",")
 euro(20)

 # 2. Method 2
 library(formattable)
 currency(20, symbol = "\U20AC", digits = 0)

 # 3. Method 3

 # 3.1. Load package
 library(DT)

 # 3.2. Create data set
 m = cbind(matrix(rnorm(120, 1e5, 1e6), 40), runif(40), rnorm(40, 100))
 colnames(m) = head(LETTERS, ncol(m))
 m

 # 3.3. Format the columns 'A' (euro), 'C' (usd), and 'D' (percentages)
 datatable(m) %>% 
   formatCurrency(c('A'), '\U20AC', digits = 0) %>% 
   formatCurrency(c('C')) %>% 
   formatPercentage('D', 2)
```

Hope one of them can be useful.