# shiny - Display Euro symbol in plots

Tags: r, shiny, axis, label, euro

I have a developed a shiny app that displays Euro amounts on the y-axis label. It does not render in the plot output. How do I get around this issue?

The following is in the `server.R`:

```
plot(monthRange, euroPerMonth/1000, 
     type="l",
     main="Cost",
     xlab="Months",
     ylab="€ (000)")
```

The closest I have come across is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706226/plotting-euro-symbol-%E2%82%AC-in-ggplot2); but, I am not sure how to apply this in shiny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following minimal example does plot the Euro sign correctly.

Place the code in a new `R` file and call it `app.R`

```
server <- function(input, output) {
output$cost <- renderPlot({
    plot(2, main="Cost", xlab="Months", ylab="€") 
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(plotOutput("cost"))
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When running this I get the following GUI with the Euro sign plotted.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: That worked. But, when triggered via a click on the Run App button, it didn't work. Text encoding is set to UTF-8.

Comment: Running the code via `cmd enter` and hitting the Run App button does produce the exact same behavior in my environment.

Comment: I am going to have to explore some more; as it does not seem to work for me. Thanks Adrian, for your response.